# What does the word 「とかいう歌」 mean?

Tags: words

I have came across the word in the following situation.

> A: What is coming to your mind when I say the word 「両{りょう}親{しん}」？
>
> B: おれは植木等のファンでね　とくにあの無{む}責{せき}任{にん}**とかいう[歌]{うた}**が大好きなんだ　両親イコールってのは...な　いい答{こた}えじゃないか

**Another question**: Does the word 「は...な」 mean 'flower'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「～～とかいう歌{うた}」 means "the/that song called something like '~~'"

「は..な」　does ***not*** mean "flower".  Not at all, I am afraid.

Those are two particles so it is pronounced 「**わな**」.  「は」 is the subject marker, naturally, and 「な」 is an interjectory particle used for assertion and/or persuasion.